# Область видимости интерфейса

Tags: java, интерфейс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И интерфейс и класс имеют модификатор доступа public. Почему нельзя декларировать переменную интерфейса в классе
?
//интерфейс

```
public interface B {
}
```

//класс

```
package com.nure;

public class A {
    private B b;
}
```

Comment: Приведите код, пожалуйста. И ошибку компилятора.

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'B'

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка «править», с помощью которой можно внести изменения. Добавьте код в сам вопрос. И включите в него интерфейс.

Comment: Значит или библиотека не подключена содержащая В,  или если она в другом namespace нужно указать явно namespace.

Comment: Забыли дописать import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В интерфейсе `B` не объявлен пакет. Это означает, что `B` находится в пакете по-умолчанию, а следовательно импортировать его нельзя и обратиться к нему из именованного пакета (`com.nure`) не получится.

Чтобы исправить:

- Пропишите пакет в файле `B.java`. Например:

  ```
  //выберите имя по вкусу
  package com.nure.interfaces;
  ```

  Перенесите файл `B.java` в соответствующую директорию.
- Если в результате `A` и `B` окажутся в разных пакетах, то импортируйте `B`:

  ```
  //в A.java
  import com.nure.interfaces.B;
  ```